# Angular Jasmine spy is not getting called when calling the next() on a subject in the test component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular8, testbed

Normally when doing an expect that a mocked service call has been called it does it succesfully. I now have the following situation in which basically all code is getting triggered but the expect for the spy to have been called does not pass.

I use the latest Karma (4.1.0) and Jasmine (3.4.0) and a Angular 8.x version.

I have the following testBed configuration and an single testsuite.

```
fdescribe('DetailComponent', () => {
  let component: DetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DetailComponent>;
  let mockedResolvedData: TimesheetResolved;
  let mockedTimesheet: Timesheet;
  let mockedPermissions;
  let mockTimesheetService;
  let mockNotificationService;
  let mockPermissionsService;
  let mockRouter;
  let mockActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockedTimesheet = mockTimesheet();
    mockedPermissions = mockPermissions();
    mockedResolvedData = { timesheet: mockedTimesheet, error: null };

    mockTimesheetService = jasmine.createSpyObj([
      'patchTimesheet',
      'getTimesheet',
    ]);
    mockNotificationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['showNotification']);
    mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getRole']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // left out MaterialDesign imports
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        DetailComponent,
        // list of MockComponents
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: TimesheetService, useValue: mockTimesheetService },
        { provide: NotificationService, useValue: mockNotificationService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthenticationService },
        { provide: NgxPermissionsService, useValue: mockPermissionsService },
      ],
    });

    mockRouter = TestBed.get(Router);
    mockActivatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
  }));

  describe('when the resolvedData is filled: happy-flow (regular behavior)', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimesheetDetailComponent);
      mockTimesheetService.getTimesheet.and.returnValue(of(mockedRefreshedTimesheet));
      mockPermissionsService.getPermissions.and.returnValue(mockedPermissions);
      mockTimesheetService.patchTimesheet.and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse<Object>()));
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

fit('should call the patch if the value from the remarkSubject is changed', () => {
    // Arrange
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Act
    component.timesheetRemarksSubject.next('new value');

    // Assert
    expect(mockTimesheetService.patchTimesheet).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The component has the following code:

```
// left out imports

@Component({
  selector: 'detail-cmp',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss'],
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly destroyed = new Subject();
  timesheetRemarksSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  timesheet: Timesheet;

  constructor(
    private readonly timesheetService: TimesheetService,
    private readonly notificationService: NotificationService,
    private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {;
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      const resolvedData: TimesheetResolved = data['resolvedData'];
      this.errorMessage = resolvedData.error;
      this.onTimesheetReceived(resolvedData.timesheet);
    });
  }

  onTimesheetReceived(timesheet: Timesheet): void {
    this.timesheet = timesheet;

    if (timesheet) {
        // do something
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.timesheet) {
      console.log('ngAfterViewInit!');
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.setupTimesheetRemarksSubjectSubscription();
    }
  }

  private setupTimesheetRemarksSubjectSubscription(): void {
    console.log('setupTimesheetRemarksSubjectSubscription');
    this.timesheetRemarksSubject
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .subscribe(remark => {
        console.log('succesfully remark object added');
        console.log('value of the remark is: ', remark);
        this.timesheet.remarks = remark;
        this.patchTimesheetRemark();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('ngOnDestroy!');
    this.destroyed.next();
    this.destroyed.complete();
  }

  private patchTimesheetRemark(): void {
    console.log('patching timesheet remarks!');
    this.timesheetService.patchTimesheet(this.timesheet.id, this.timesheet.remarks).subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log('succesfully patched');
        this.notificationService.showNotification(//custom message);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When making a custom out of the box component, barebones with the same kind of dependencies my spy is getting called... Which is weird because my setup is basically the same. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bv7oj2 <- here is the barebones project. Probably best to just copy paste this in a barebones angular CLI project and run `ng test`.

Bottomline is, something in my setup/configuration is different because in the barebones it works. The spy is getting called. In my own test it doesn't. I receive the following console logs:

[image]

this in combination with a failed test display:

[image]

I am a bit clueless in why the spy is not getting called. I left out of the most unimportant stuff out of the code, so if I'm missing something please tell me and I will provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an async test with a debounceTime. To get angular to wait for that time inside your test you need to make this test a fakeAsync test and then call tick(500) before making that assert. Have a look here https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig, this works. Can you make this an answer so I can mark it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an async test you need to make sure that the test waits especially if your test includes a `debounceTime`. For that you can use a `fakeAsync` test setup and call `tick(500)` where the 500 is the time you have set as a debounce time.

The tick tells the test to actually wait for that debounceTime to be finished and only once that's over your spy gets invoked.

Have a look here: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: Thanks a lot erbsen, obvious mistake I should've seen before but sometimes it helps to let someone else look at it! Thanks!